# setting z-index for particle effect in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

Is it possible to set z-index for particle effet in libgdx? For example class Image has setZIndex method, but in case of ParticleEffect or ParticleEmitter class I am not able to find an appropriate method for such purpose.

I tried to use BoundingBox and set center z, but it is not working as I expected.

Unfortunately documentation is not helpful in this matter.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you using scene2d for you non-particle stuff?

Comment: Yes, I add all objects to Stage as actors. To make my particle effect an actor (only actors can be added to the stage) I prepared a wrapper which extends Image class and via composition handles drawing and acting of particle effect.

Comment: Sounds like that should work. `setZIndex` is a method of the Actor class, so all subclasses should support it automatically. Keep in mind that the Z index is only compared with other actors in the same group. For example, if `group1` has a bunch of actors with Z index's from 1-10, and `group2` has an actor with Z index of 1000, the actor in `group2` will still be drawn behind all the actors in `group1` if `group2` itself has a lower Z index than `group1` itself.